# How to filter time hierarchy based on anothr attribute's value in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to create a calculated member. I have a time dimension hierarchy" YQM", which has Year/Quarter/Month.  The calculated member should find YTD till the current month.  However, the value of current month will come from database.
I have created a attribute, "CP" which returns the current month value.
Please tell me how to create the calculated member. Please note "CP" is not in the same hierarchy YQM.

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Is this current month value dynamic? Does it change from month to month? Could you please add here some initial values and expected result?

Comment: I don't understand because surely future dates do not have any data - so YTD is just the results for this year?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using `Aggregate`. So, I will assume that it is there for some purpose, which you have't clarified. Now, if the members of `[YQM].[Month]` and `[Dim].[CP]` are of the same format, then you can try the code below:

```
   Aggregate(
        PeriodsToDate([Dim].[YQM].[Month].MEMBERS,
            FILTER([Dim].[YQM].[Month].MEMBERS, 
            [YQM].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER.member_value = [Dim].[CP].FirstChild.member_value)
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try playing with the function `YTD`. The following should give you the monthly amount in the first column of data and then the YTD amount in the next column:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[YearToDate] AS
  AGGREGATE(
    YTD()
   ,[Measures].[someMeasureInCube]
  )
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[someMeasureInCube], 
    [Measures].[YearToDate]
  } ON 0,
  [Dim].[YQM].[Month].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [yourCube]
```